# In iPhone device, VPN profile showing "unknown" when installed, in Settings -> VPN screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, vpn

I created VPN profile using Apple Configurator 2, VPN is working fine. In iPhone Settings -> VPN screen, its showing "unknown" below profile name. I am not able to find where can I add description to the profile. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes your question a programming one?  How does the swift tag come into play?

Comment: I was facing same issue due to server setup issue. When server guys fix issue then it was fix on app end too. 

So it may be issue of     

-Server setup issue.  

-Username/Password (shared by networking team)
-Server certificate Keys.

are you using firebase for user detail?